# Prevent Form from submitting on date validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is my code, where two dates are compared and gives a alert in span block.
I want to check if **CheckInDate < today** then, the form should not be submitted.

```
$(document.getElementsByName("CheckInDate")).on("change", function () {
    var CheckInDate = $(document.getElementsByName("CheckInDate")).val();
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var c = CheckInDate.split("-");
    var cdd = c[0];
    var cmm = c[1];
    var cyyyy = c[2];
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
    if((cyyyy < yyyy) || (cyyyy == yyyy && cmm < mm) || (cyyyy == yyyy && cmm == mm && cdd < dd))
    {
        document.getElementById("DateWarning").innerHTML = "WrongDate";
        /* Form Should not be submitted */
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("DateWarning").innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

I want to prevent the form from submitting. How can I do this?

Comment: can you please provide the code of the form?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues such as mixing jQuery and DOM

You want to prevent the submission by hooking the submit event like this:

```
$(function() { // on load 
    $("#formId").on("submit", function (e) { // use the form submit event
      var CheckInDate = $("#CheckInDate").val();
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var c = CheckInDate.split("-");
      var cdd = c[0];
      var cmm = c[1];
      var cyyyy = c[2];
      var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if(dd<10) {
          dd='0'+dd
      } 
      if(mm<10) {
          mm='0'+mm
      } 
      today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
      if((cyyyy < yyyy) || (cyyyy == yyyy && cmm < mm) || (cyyyy == yyyy && cmm == mm && cdd < dd)) {
        $("#DateWarning").html("WrongDate");
        e.preventDefault(); // cancel submission
      }
      else {
        $("#DateWarning").html("")
      }
    });
});
```

If you want to test the date on change of the date field, you need a function you can reuse:

```
function checkDate() {
  var CheckInDate = $("#CheckInDate").val();
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var c = CheckInDate.split("-");
  var cdd = c[0];
  var cmm = c[1];
  var cyyyy = c[2];
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10) {
      dd='0'+dd
  } 
  if(mm<10) {
      mm='0'+mm
  } 
  today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
  if((cyyyy < yyyy) || (cyyyy == yyyy && cmm < mm) || (cyyyy == yyyy && cmm == mm && cdd < dd)) {
    $("#DateWarning").html("WrongDate");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    $("#DateWarning").html("");
    return true;
  }
}
$(function() {
  $("#formId").on("submit", function (e) { // use the form submit event
    if (!checkDate()) e.preventDefault();
  });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Form submission should be prevented at the `onsubmit` event:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
   if(preventCondition)
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

So it is at that point you need to check if the form is valid. You may very well perform the check at `onchange` of that field, to provide client feedback, but you should either re-validate at form submission, or have the validation set a flag that you check for later.